# Not able to integrate Node.js API in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend

I am not able to save data in the database using Node.js API and Reactjs

Here is the Reactjs code

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function SignUp() {
    const [Name, setName] = useState("");
    const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");
    
    async function Collectdata() {
        let result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/Login", {
            method: "post",
            body: JSON.stringify({ Name, Email, Password }),
            headers: { 
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
             }
        });
        result = await result.json();
      console.log(result);
    }
    return (
        <div className="Maindiv">

            <form className="Signup_page" >
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" id="name" onChange={(e) => { setName(e.target.value) }}></input>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }}></input>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }}></input>
                <div className="signup-buttons">
                    <button onClick={Collectdata}>Log in</button>
                    <button onClick={Collectdata}>Sign up</button>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
    )
}
export default SignUp;
```

Here is the Node.js API code

```
const express = require("express");
require("./dbconnect");
const cors = require("cors");
const user = require("./schema");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/Login",async (req,resp)=>{
     user.insertMany(req.body);

})

app.listen(5000);
```

Assuming that there is no problem in database connection here, I am trying to insert the form data into the database, but there is some problem in the `Collectdata` function, preventing that. I also do not see the `console.log(result)` in the console.

Comment: Your server doesn't return anything, so what log are you expecting exactly? Also, you probably should await the insertMany call (which realistically should be a select query for login, inserting would be  sign-up)

Comment: I suggest you test your api using libraries like supertest before writing UI code